# Does “Anyone who does this, he will be punished severely” sound right?

Tags: grammar, commas

> Anyone who does this, he will be punished severely.

This is a sentence structure that is very frequently used. But there are two clauses that are connected only by a comma that does not serve as any type of coordinating conjunction. But it makes perfect sense and is grammatically correct for some reasons. Any explanations please?

Comment: It's a construction typical of non-native speakers. The actual native speakers would normally express this as either *Anyone who does this will be punished severely* or *If anyone does this he will be punished severely.* Actually, native speakers are much more likely to say [***severely punished***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+punished+severely%2Cbe+severely+punished&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20punished%20severely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbe%20severely%20punished%3B%2Cc0), but that's a whole nother story.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @FumbleFingers.  If you're hearing this frequently it's likely a function of who you hang out with.  Remember, grammar only takes you so far.  It won't help you find or construct Idioms.

Comment: Purely an opinion, but I have the feeling it's particularly people from *Far Eastern* countries who do this. I find it easier to imagine hearing it in a Chinese or Korean accent than from a European mainlander or an Indian, for example. Someone who knows more than me about oriental languages may be able to explain how the cited usage "translates".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think there's anything foreign-sounding about *punished severely*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not entirely sure if the sentence is foreign sounding. Even though your native version sounds more correct, the sentence jwassuarez has posted was even used in a movie. And I am sure the one who spoke it was native American.

Comment: No, it's not "foreign". It's Left Dislocation, exactly parallel to _My old man, he can whip anybody._ [Dislocation rules](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) move subject or object constituents to the front (Left Dislocation) or the end (Right Dislocation) of a sentence for emphasis, and leave a pronoun behind. Thus they're copying rules, not movement rules, so they're not subject to Ross constraints.

Comment: @John, sooeithdk: I did say *typically* (used by nns) and that native speakers *normally* use (what I'd consider more "standard") alternatives. Me (or *Myself*, or *Personally*), I wouldn't see anything "wrong" with the usage. But I do have the impression OP's exact citation is more common among nns, and it just seemed to me at least possible this is because it reflects a type of construction that's more common in oriental languages. Not that I know anything to support that assumption, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

This construction is known as *[dislocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_%28syntax%29)* (specifically *left dislocation*): the noun phrase "Anyone who does this", which would normally be expected to be the subject of "will be punished severely", has instead been moved to the left, and a pronoun has taken its place. The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL) gives this (contrived) example that is similar to yours:

> Her parents, they seem pretty uncaring.

Note that this phenomenon is not restricted to the subject of a clause, and that the detached element (here "Her parents") and the pronoun (here "they") need not end up adjacent; for example, here is another (contrived) example from CGEL:

> Her parents, I don't like them at all.

Dislocation is much less common in English than in some languages, which — if I may speculate a bit — may account for FumbleFingers' observation above that this is "a construction typical of non-native speakers". (Another possibility I can think of is that speakers of [null-subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language) or [pro-drop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language) languages may have difficulty keeping track of when a subject pronoun is required, and may sometimes translate source-language {verb} to English {pronoun + verb} even when a subject is already present.)

However, this construction *does* occur in the English of at least some native speakers. My impression is that it's particularly common in pop music; I imagine that this is for metrical reasons (the need to put pauses and beats and so on in the right places), but it may also be that pop music is influenced by dialects of English that I'm not otherwise much exposed to. (Maybe AAVE? I used to have much more interaction with AAVE speakers than I do now; I can't remember whether they used this sort of construction.) Here are some pop-music examples I can think of offhand:

> - Yeah, my momma she told me don't worry about your size. — Meghan Trainor, "All About That Bass"
> - Some say love, it is a river / That drowns the tender reed. — Bette Midler, "The Rose"

Comment: My momma and love are not the same as "anyone who..." but point well taken.

Comment: Exactly. I think your pop example is a bit out of place. Especially that "some say love..river."